# Mysql - How to find max Value with decimal

Tags: mysql, sql, max

In the mysql table (books_title) have 144 records.
The column book_progressive contain this values for rows:
01.01
02.01
03.01
...
99.01
100.01
101.01
102.01
...
144.01

When check the max value with this query:

```
select max(book_progressive) from books_title
```

return 99.01, but the max value is 144.01.

How to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: it seems like the datatype of your field is varchar instead of decimal

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself... The MySQL code to reproduce this is missing

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your book_progressive is declared as CHAR/VARCHAR and not DECIMAL.

Change your column type , or CAST the result :

```
select max(CAST(book_progressive AS DECIMAL(10,2)) from books_title
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is valid

Comment: Changing your columns datatype from CHAR/VARCHAR to DECIMAL is your best option @Frankie

Comment: Not changing a datatype. I use LPAD to resolve this.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I would not say its the best option. It MIGHT be the best option. Let's say he only needs a number in the current context and that changing the column to Number implies a lot of  changes in the underlying application (removing surrounding quotes in queries, etc...) that would implies bugs everywhere, then it is not the best solution anymore. That's not black or white.

Answer (score 0):

I find a Solution with LPAD because the max value is found only if the number of characters is equal

```
select max(lpad(book_progressive,6,0)) from books_title
```

Thans

Comment: LPAD is a very very bad idea.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b50c09/5  Change your column type , or CAST the result like Thomas said